# Django can't flush database during tests

Tags: python, django, postgresql, testing

When trying to run my tests (python manage.py test) I am getting:

```
CommandError: Database test_db couldn't be flushed. Possible reasons:
  * The database isn't running or isn't configured correctly.
  * At least one of the expected database tables doesn't exist.
  * The SQL was invalid.
Hint: Look at the output of 'django-admin.py sqlflush'. That's the SQL this command wasn't able to run.
The full error: cannot truncate a table referenced in a foreign key constraint
DETAIL:  Table "install_location_2015_05_13" references "app".
HINT:  Truncate table "install_location_2015_05_13" at the same time, or use TRUNCATE ... CASCADE.
```

I am using [partitions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/ddl-partitioning.html) in our project which are generated on the fly via a python function (so I can run it periodically). I don't have any models for these partitions.

The partition maintenance function is invoked after *syncdb* triggers the *post_syncdb* signal (so it is executed when the test database is set up).

How can I make Django clear the additional tables (partitions)? or
How can I tell Django to use CASCADE while running the tests?

Answer (score 0):

Mainly problem occur where we change relation in M2M field. Old constraint remain and new constraint for new relation was created. [Fixed in Django 1.8](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/6820)

Comment: I still experience that with Django==2.0.2

Comment: me too with Django==3.1.2

Comment: the problem is still present on django==4.2.10